# "search in" vs "search on"

Tags: prepositions

When talking about searching something in/on the dictionary (e.g. meaning of word), should I say

I **searched on** the dictionary or I **searched in** the dictionary?

Comment: You search a dictionary or search in/through a dictionary for a word.

Comment: Would've been better if you'd presented some research, btw. :)

Comment: If it's an online dictionary, you search *on* it! Anything on the Internet takes 'on'. So, you search on, log on... However, if you go in *further*, you log *in*!

Comment: You search a dictionary to find the answer to a question like this.

Comment: @Maulik Anything?! What about _chat room_? "We were talking in/on this online chat room."

Comment: Read that again! I said anything that goes *further in* is 'in'. You are **on** stackexchange and *further in..* you are *in chatroom*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have to choose between *search in a dictionary* and *search on a dictionary*, definitely go for *in*. 
Here is the entry for [**search**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/search_2) in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:

> **1** <sup>LOOKING [intransitive and transitive]</sup> to try to find someone or something by looking very carefully:
>   *It was too dark to search further.*
>   *The area was thoroughly searched.*
>   **search for**
>   *An RAF plane searched for the missing men.*
>   *I've searched high and low* (=everywhere) *for my glasses.*
>   **search something for something**
>   *Detectives are searching the yard for clues.*
>   **search in/under/through etc**
>   *Alice bent to search through a heap of clothes.*
>
> **2** <sup>COMPUTER [transitive]</sup> to use a computer to find information:
>   **search something for something**
>   *Search the Web for cheap flights.*

But as suggested by Longman's second definition above, another alternative would be ***search a dictionary** (for the definition of a word, etc)*, which turns out to be favored over the construction with *in*. [N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=search+the+dictionary%2Csearch+in+the+dictionary&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csearch%20the%20dictionary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csearch%20in%20the%20dictionary%3B%2Cc0):
[image]

But not even that is the best choice of words. Here are the verb collocations that Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English provides for *dictionary*:

> **use a dictionary**: *We advise all our students to use a good dictionary.*
>   **look something up in a dictionary**: *If you don’t understand the meaning of a word, look it up in a dictionary.*
>   **check a dictionary**: *I often check the dictionary for spelling and pronunciation.*
>   **consult a dictionary** (formal) (=check something in a dictionary): *Consult the dictionary for examples of how a word is used.*

And searching [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for `look up, dictionary` and `search, dictionary` collocations reveals that the former is much more commonly used than the latter (by a factor of about ten).

So, to conclude, I suggest that you use *[**look up**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/look-up?q=look+up) (a word, a definition, etc) in the dictionary*:

> **look something ↔ up**
>   to look for information in a dictionary or reference book, or by using a computer
>   *Can you look up the opening times on the website?*
>   *I looked it up in the dictionary.*

Answer (score 3):

The specific answer to your question is that one searches **in** a dictionary. One may conceptualize it as opening the book and looking inside.

One may search on a surface for something. For example, "search on the table for the dice" (though I might prefer "look on the table" rather than "search", using look as a synonym for search in that case). Searching "on the dictionary" would imply looking on top of the book rather than inside it for an answer.

I supposed more generally, if something is opened, then one searches inside it. For example, I search in the trunk for my lost gold. For things that have a surface, one searches on [top of] the surface: I search on [top of] the trunk for my carelessly discarded cardigan.

Comment: **searched in** is not restricted to things that you open. You can also search in a confined space, for example "I searched for the photos **in** the attic".

Comment: @JavaLatte, you are correct that an area that can be entered is also "searched in." I was thinking this morning that it is also interesting that one searches on the internet, even though it really has no existence. But can can "log on" or "log in" to a web site.

Comment: "log in" predates the internet by a loooong way. See this: http://www.designcult.org/2011/08/why-do-we-call-in-logging-in.html. From then on, each computer manufacturer had their own preferred term- IBM went for logon. In 1995 the internet went public and "log on" had a brief period of dominance, but now "log in" is ahead again. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=log+in%2Clog+on&year_start=1980&year_end=2009&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clog%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clog%20on%3B%2Cc0